# Pass actual ID to find by reference rather than the actual Value

Tags: php, laravel

```
$division =Division::find('id = ?',20);
```

I am trying to write something like shown above eloquent query. I really don't want to pass the actual value directly to avoid sql injections. is it possible to write an expression like that in Laravel find() or i will have to pass the value directly

Comment: Eloquent already provides protection agains SQL injections in this case; if you do a QueryLog you will find the bindings and see query with ? as placeholders.

Comment: Thanks wanted to be sure eloquent do  provide protection for this also

Answer (score 0):

```
**Eloquent uses parameter binding behind the scene, which safely escapes any input**
$division = Division::findOrFail(intval($id));
```